# How to change the order of triple summation?

Tags: combinatorics, summation

How to change summation in the sum 
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n  \left(\sum_{j=1}^i \sum_{k=j}^i b_{j,k} \right) a_i? 
$$

For $n=4$ we have 
$$
\sum_{i=0}^4  \left(\sum_{j=1}^i \sum_{k=j}^i b_{j,k} \right) a_i=f_{{1,1}}a_{{1}}+a_{{2}} \left( f_{{1,1}}+f_{{1,2}}+f_{{2,2}} \right) 
+a_{{3}} \left( f_{{1,1}}+f_{{1,2}}+f_{{1,3}}+f_{{2,2}}+f_{{2,3}}+f_{{
3,3}} \right) +a_{{4}} \left( f_{{1,1}}+f_{{1,2}}+f_{{1,3}}+f_{{1,4}}+
f_{{2,2}}+f_{{2,3}}+f_{{2,4}}+f_{{3,3}}+f_{{3,4}}+f_{{4,4}} \right)=f_{{1,1}} \left( a_{{1}}+a_{{2}}+a_{{3}}+a_{{4}} \right) +f_{{2,2}}
 \left( a_{{2}}+a_{{3}}+a_{{4}} \right) +f_{{3,3}} \left( a_{{3}}+a_{{
4}} \right) +f_{{4,4}}a_{{4}}+f_{{2,1}}a_{{2}}+a_{{3}} \left( f_{{2,1}
}+f_{{3,1}}+f_{{3,2}} \right) +a_{{4}} \left( f_{{2,1}}+f_{{3,1}}+f_{{
4,1}}+f_{{3,2}}+f_{{4,2}}+f_{{4,3}} \right)
$$I guess it must be    something like that
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n  \left(\sum_{j=1}^i \sum_{k=j}^i b_{j,k} \right) a_i=\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=j}^? \left(\sum_{i=?}^? a_i \right) b_{j,k}
$$
but  can't find true limits.
Any ideas?

Comment: There are six (and not two) nesting orders in which the summation can be performed. Your first displayed formula exhibits one of these. You have to tell us which is the intended final nesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is helpful to write the range of summation in terms of inequalities. In your case it turns out to be $$\begin{align}0 &\leq i \leq n\\ 1&\leq j\leq i\\ j&\leq k\leq i\end{align}\tag{1}$$ and you can check that this is equivalent to $$1\leq j \leq k \leq i \leq n.\tag{2}$$ Notice that the original order of indices is $(i,j,k)$ and take a look at $(1)$. In the first line $i$ "doesn't know about" $j$ or $k$, so it is just $1\leq i \leq n$ ($i = 0$ doesn't actually appear in the sum). In the second line, $j$ "doesn't know about" $k$, but it "does know" $i$, so it is $1\leq j \leq i$. Finally, $k$ "knows everyone", so the third line becomes $j\leq k\leq i$.

Let us now change the order to $(j,k,i)$. From $(2)$ we read that the first line has to be $1\leq j\leq n$ since $j$ "doesn't know about" $k$ and $i$. The second line is $j\leq k \leq n$ since $k$ "doesn't know" $i$, but "knows" $j$. Finally, the third line is $k\leq i\leq n$ since $i$ "knows everyone".

Thus, the change of order of summation you want is $$\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=j}^n\sum_{i=k}^n$$

Answer (score 1):

$i$ from  $k$ to $n$, $k$ from $j$ to $n$.

Answer (score 1):

*Note:* It is also common to do the transformation using the sigma-notation.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{i=0}^n\left(\sum_{j=1}^i\sum_{k=j}^ib_{j,k}\right)a_i}
> &=\sum_{i=0}^n\left(\sum_{1\leq j\leq k\leq i}b_{j,k}\right)a_i\\
> &=\sum_{1\leq j\leq k\leq i\leq n} a_ib_{j,k}\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{j\leq k\leq i\leq n}a_ib_{j,k}\\
> &=\,\,\color{blue}{\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=j}^n\left(\sum_{i=k}^na_i\right)b_{j,k}}
> \end{align*}